# Can a self adjoint positive operator have a square root that is not comparable to 0?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

So, I've just learned about the definition of the square root of a positive self adjoint operator in a Hilbert space, and seen the proof that it has a unique positive square root.  (Which would then induce a negative square root,  of course).

My question is:  Can we have a positive self adjoint operator $T$ such that there exists a self adjoint operator $S$  such that $S^2=T$  but $S$ is not comparable to $0$?  This is more idle curiosity than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $T =\rm{id}$ and $S= \rm{diag}(1,-1)$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$.